# What do i need to add to my python code for the coin toss problem?

Tags: python

> Write a function named coinToss that simulates the tossing of a coin. When you call the function, it should generate a random number in the range of 1 through 2. If the random number is 1, the function should display “heads.” If the random number is 2, the function should display “tails.” Demonstrate the function in a program that asks the user how many times the coin should be tossed and then simulates the tossing of the coin that number of times.

```
import random #this imports random

flips = int(input("How many coin flips? ")) #this asks user how many coin flips to use

def tossCoin(flips): #this defines the function tossCoin
    result = random.randint(1,2) #this assigns a random number for the flip
    for amount in range(flips):
        if (result == 1): 
            return("Heads")
        else: 
            if(result == 2): 
                return("Tails")

print(tossCoin(flips)) #this prints tossCoin
```

Comment: well, just loop to call your function instead of returning immediately.

Comment: I think you need to know how to use a debugger. The error will be obvious then

Comment: You are only getting a random number one time, then running every coin toss with that same result, I would move `result = random.randit(1,2)` inside your for loop so you get a new random number every for each flip, on mobile or I would write out full answer sorry

Comment: If you read the task carefully you'll see "[...] the function should display [...]" and [...] simulates the tossing of a coin [...]" (it's **_a_** coin, not multiple coins). Use `print` in your function and put the loop out of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `"Heads"` and `"Tails"` stops the `for` loop during the first iteration.

```
print("Heads")
```

and

```
print("Tails")
```

should be used instead.

This line should be inside the `for` loop to generate a random number for each flip.

```
result = random.randint(1,2)
```